# All attempts to add packages fail

Tags: apt, 18.04, webmin

Brand new 18.04.02 install.  Added Webmin & it worked.
Now can't add anything at all.  Webmin fails with 404 - file not found
Command line fails with

```
After this operation, 6,985 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

The abort is automatic.  Both appear to read the repositories so what file is not found?

Update to original.  The process is:

[don@email ~]# sudo apt install apache2

> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
>
> Reading package lists...
> Building dependency tree...
> Reading state information...
> The following additional packages will be installed:
> apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1
> libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.2-0 ssl-cert
> Suggested packages:
> www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
> openssl-blacklist
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1
> libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.2-0 ssl-cert
> 0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
> Need to get 1,730 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 6,985 kB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.

[don@email ~]#

Comment: We don't know where you got Webmin from (we do know it wasn't us), nor which instructions you followed to install it, nor how well you followed those instructions. Seems like a Webmin support question. If you have a problem with the underlying 18.04 OS, we'll happily answer questions about that.

Comment: Webmin fail and tells me a 404 error.  
apt fails by Abort at the "Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort" as shown in the question.

Comment: Exactly what shell command are you using that causes the automatic abort? Please edit your question to show us the complete input and output.

Comment: 404 usually means it can not find a web address to install the package from. check your network connections and repositories.

Comment: I am assuming there is some strange permissions conflict because:
 - Using Webmin's remote terminal "sudo apt install" xxx Aborts whereas on the console it works.
 - Using Webmin's add software, it dies with a "404 File not found"
 - BUT once something is installed, using Webmin, to update it, with through the GUI or with a terminal session works fine.

Damned if I know what the difference is.